# How to use breezejs with existing web services?

Tags: breeze, single-page-application

I need to use breeze js and angular js for my SPA project.that develop on the existing web services. can i use breezejs API with these type of project ?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by creating a breeze controller and call existing web service from this controller.